# como guardar en un label el valor devuelto de un onClick()

Tags: vb.net, funciones, id

tengo lo siguiente:

```
<td align="left">
             <asp:Label ID="resultado" runat="server" Text="resultado"></asp:Label>
                         <a class="badge badge-success" onclick="siresultado()">ok</a>
                         <a class="badge badge-important" onclick="noresultado()">no</a>                           
 </td>
```

necesito que en el `id="resultado"` quede guardado el resultado de onclick, en este caso el valor obtenido de `siresultado()` o `noresultado()`.

que me está faltando!!

Answer (score 1):

lo que necesitas es enviar el objeto que supongo que es lo que buscas, agregando la palabra `this` y luego, en las funciones declaras una variable de entrada y muestras o manipulas su valor.

```js
function siresultado(variable){
document.getElementById("resultado").innerText= variable.text;
}
function noresultado(variable){
document.getElementById("resultado").innerText= variable.text;
}
```

```html
<td align="left">
  <label ID="resultado" runat="server" Text="resultado"></label>
  <a class="badge badge-success" onclick="siresultado(this)">ok</a>
  <a class="badge badge-important" onclick="noresultado(this)">no</a>
</td>
```

Comment: no me funcionó correctamente.  cuando llamo a ese "resultado"  con un get que tengo creado no me lo toma, me da error cuando cargo la pagina.

porque la variable es .text?

Comment: Amigo, por que necesitas llamar a ese resultado con un get? lo deje en funciones para que no tuvieses problemas al manipularlo. Si quieres te puedo orientar pero tienes que compartir TU CODIGO para poder ayudarte. La variable es text por que estas enviando el objeto <a> completo, si quieres enviar solo el texto debes colocar siresultado(this.text). Como recomendación, di que error te sale, coloca tu codigo. @AgustinCallieri

Comment: el error dice : error 500 internal server.

esta es mi otra parte del código:
function siguiente() {
             pagAct += 1;
             var fechaD = $('#<%=tbFechaDesde.ClientID%>').val();
             var fechaH = $('#<%=tbFechaHasta.ClientID%>').val();
             var dep = $('#cbSucursal1').val();
            var resultado = $('#resultado').val();
             getListaMovStock(pagAct, cantReg, fechaD, fechaH, dep, Codigo, resultado);
         }

necesito llamar a ese get porque obtiene otras variables.

Comment: 3 Cosas, 1, por favor lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y **edita** tu pregunta, no coloques código acá, 2.- El error 500 es un error por lado servidor, por lo que nos ayudaría a ayudarte el que puedas decirnos mas respecto a tu backend o depurando en que parte de tu backend manda el error y 3.- Coloca el código de tu backend tambien pero **EDITANDO** tu pregunta.